# "React Query: Correctly Tracking isLoading for Parallel Queries Triggered by Multiple Buttons"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tanstackreact-query

I'm currently working with React Query, and I've encountered a challenge in tracking the isLoading status for parallel queries triggered by multiple buttons. I've managed to correctly track the isLoading status when I click a single button and wait for the query to complete. However, when I press two buttons simultaneously, the isLoading status for the first button I clicked doesn't return accurately.

Here's the situation:

1. I have multiple buttons, and each button triggers a different query using React Query.
2. I'm using a custom hook, useCancelOrder, which returns a useMutation hook for making mutations.
3. When I click a button, I call createMutation({ symbol, orderId }) to create a mutation instance and retrieve the mutateAsync function.
4. I want to display a loading indicator specific to each button/query so that users can see the loading status for each action.
5. When I click a single button, the isLoading status works as expected, and I can display a loading indicator until the query finishes.
6. However, when I click two buttons simultaneously, the isLoading status for the first button I clicked doesn't return correctly, and it doesn't accurately reflect the loading state of that specific query.

I'm seeking advice or guidance on how to ensure that the isLoading status for each query/button remains accurate, even when multiple buttons are clicked simultaneously. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!ry independently, so I can display loading indicators and manage the UI based on the loading status of each query.

Any suggestions or insights on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { API_URL, getServerTime } from "@/util/cryptoConfig";
import { postData } from "./usePostData";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { AxiosError } from "../types/types";
import axios from "axios";
import PQueue from "p-queue";

// Initialize order cancellation queues for each order ID
const userCancelOrderQueues: { [orderId: number]: PQueue } = {};

export const cancelOrder = async ({
  symbol,
  orderId,
}: {
  symbol: string;
  orderId: number;
}) => {
  if (!userCancelOrderQueues[orderId]) {
    userCancelOrderQueues[orderId] = new PQueue({ concurrency: 1 });
  }

  return userCancelOrderQueues[orderId].add(async () => {
    let timestampResult;
    try {
      timestampResult = await getServerTime();

      const params = {
        symbol,
        orderId,
        timestamp: timestampResult,
      };

      const config = await postData(params);

      const response = await axios.post(`/api/post`, {
        command: "DELETE",
        baseUrl: `${API_URL}/fapi/v1/order`,
        config: config,
      });

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  });
};

export const useCancelOrder = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const mutation = useMutation(cancelOrder, {
    onSuccess: async (data) => {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["openOrders"] });
      console.log("Order canceled successfully", data);
    },
    onError: (error: AxiosError) => {
      let errorMsg = error.message;
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        const serverError = error.response.data;
        errorMsg = `${serverError.msg}`;
      }
      console.error("Error canceling order", errorMsg);
      toast.error(errorMsg, {
        position: "bottom-right",
        autoClose: 5000,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
        theme: "dark",
      });
    },
  });

  return {
    mutateAsync: mutation.mutateAsync,
    isLoading: mutation.isLoading,
    isSuccess: mutation.isSuccess,
  };
};
```

```
import { useCancelOrder } from "@/hooks/useCancelOrder";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BiSolidTrash } from "react-icons/bi";
import { useIsMutating, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

type CancelButtonProps = {
  index: number;
  symbol: string;
  orderId: number;
  className?: string;
  onProcessingChange?: (isProcessing: boolean) => void;
};

export default function CancelButton({
  orderId,
  symbol,
  className,
  index,
  onProcessingChange,
}: CancelButtonProps) {
  const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useCancelOrder();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const handleCloseClick = async () => {
    try {
      await mutateAsync({ symbol, orderId });
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["openOrders"] });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    } finally {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["openOrders"] });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onProcessingChange?.(isLoading);
  }, [isLoading, onProcessingChange]);

  return (
    <div
      className={`${className} relative flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-[70px] border-b border-gray ${
        index === 0 ? "border-t" : ""
      }`}
    >
      <button onClick={handleCloseClick}>
        <BiSolidTrash className="absolute bottom-3 right-6 h-5 w-5 hover:text-yellow" />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```